# Creating a balance table on Python (edited)

Tags: python

I have this code which display the payment I need to make to student loan depending on different factors but I was wondering how could I display a table telling me for example... if my program says that I'll be making 36 payments of $153.02 to pay a loan of 5000 at 6.4% interest, how do I display a table telling me (payment 1 of 153 this is the remaining balance, this much goes to interest or to principal payment, then the same payment 2 this the new balance... and so on...) In other words a table telling me about those 36 payments and how my balance gets reduced with each payment.

IT DOESN'T HAVE TO BE AS A TABLE MAYBE JUST A LIST... LISTING PAYMENT AFTER PAYMENT UNTILL THE BALANCE IS 0 or -SOMETHING?

This is the code I have so far using python 2.7.3

```
def calcDebt (principal, interestRate, numPayments, freqPayment):
    #This code will make different predictions to pay off student loan
    #Input Meanings
    '''
    Inputs
    - interestRate  - The Interest Rate of a Loan
    - numPayments - The Number of Payments Needed
    - principal - The Original Student Loan Amount
    - freqPayment - Frequency of Payments Based on Weekly, Monthly, Annually
    Returns
    - paymentAmount - The Payment Amount Will Be
    '''

    freqPayment_lookup = {'weekly': 52, 'monthly':12, 'annually':1}
    interestRate = float(interestRate) / 100

    x = interestRate/freqPayment_lookup[freqPayment]
    y = (1.0 + x) ** numPayments
    z = x/(y - 1.0)
    paymentAmount = (x + z) * principal

    return paymentAmount
def main():
    a = input('Student Loan Amount: ')
    i = input('Student Loan Interest Rate: ')
    n = input('Number of Payments: ')
    f = None
    while f not in ['weekly', 'monthly', 'annually']:
        if f:
            f = raw_input('Sorry! That is NOT an Option. Please Enter weekly, monthly,    or annually: ').lower()
    else:
            f = raw_input('How Often Do You Want To Make Your Payments? ').lower()
    payment = calcDebt(a, i, n, f)
    print 'Your %s payment will be %.2f' % (f, payment)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    raw_input('Please Press Enter to Exit')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the best thing for this is to use numpy! here is a general idea for the kind of code you would need:

```
import numpy as np
#this creates your table with numPayments rows and 4 columns
numPayments = 40
row_index = range(1,numPayments + 1)
real_row_index = []
for i in row_index:
    real_row_index.append(str(i))
columns = ["payment number", "remaining balance", "interest amount", "principal amount"]
total_payments = np.chararray((numPayments,3), itemsize=20)
total_payments[:] = "none"
total_payments = np.insert(total_payments, 0, np.array((real_row_index)),1)
total_payments = np.insert(total_payments, 0, np.array((columns)),0)
for row in total_payments[1::,1::]: 
    #the 1 skips the lables so you don't mess with them
    #row[0] will be the number payment column
    #row[1] will be the remaining balance column
    #row[2] will be the interest amount column
    #row[3] will be the principal amount column
```

now that you have an array of tables set up in a for loop (which I will not finish for you), you can use it in you function to iterate through and for every payment, set the cell to the correct value for the column. So if you calculate the interest amount in a variable interest, you just need to throw this in your for loop to make the interest that belongs in the right place to go there:

```
row[2] = str(interest)
```

interest is iterating at the same pace row is, so they should match up if done correctly

Comment: Awesome thanks!!!! Hi Ryan one question about it... this table code should go at the end of my code but before the part that helps me exit the program right?

Comment: numpy is a package for python made for manipulating multidimensional arrays and things like that. Please upvote and check to say that this is what you were looking for. And yeah you could put it there